# Java ResultSet Column count is always 1

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to show the Column numbers of a table but it always shows the number 1. I have written the code below:

```
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
java.sql.Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS); 

try (Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement()) {
            String sql;

            sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
                   table_name=\"my_b\"";

            try ( 
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
                int columCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                System.out.println("Column number is: "+columCount);
            }
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
```

Where is the error ?

Comment: When i am testing on MySql termina this: 

SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
                   table_name=\"my_b\"

Then I get correct result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ResultSet.getColumnCount` returns the number of columns in the query's result set, not the number of columns in a table.

If you are trying to get a count of columns on a table, the query you have is correct.  You just need to retrieve the result of the query, rather than its metadata.

```
        String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name=\"my_b\"";

        try ( 
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql));
            rs.next();
            int columCount = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("Column number is: " + columCount);
        }
```

Comment: Then it's give no output. :(

Comment: It has to give output.  System.out.println will output at least something, even if the count is wrong.  Are you getting an exception or something?  Please be specific.

Comment: You need to call `rs.next()` first, a result set is initially located **before** the first row.

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't needed `Class.forName` to load your JDBC drivers in a long time. Second, you are selecting a value but you are reading metadata. Third, when using `try-with-resources` you don't need explicit close calls (and your `Connection` should be closed in a `finally`, for example). Finally, use `PreparedStatement` and bind parameters. Like,

```
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name=?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
    stmt.setString(1, "my_b");
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            int columCount = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("Column number is: " + columCount);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No rows");
        }
    }
} finally {
    con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not retrieving the result of the query, instead you are asking the result set **metadata** how many columns the result set has. And as your query only produce a single column (ie `COUNT(*)`), the result of `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount()` is `1`, and that value is correct.

If you want to get the **result** of the query, you need to get it from the result set:

```
try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
    if (rs.next()) {
        int columnsNumber = rs.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("Column number is: "+columnsNumber );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
java.sql.Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS); 

try (Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement()) {
            String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE table_schema = 'database_name' AND table_name = 'table_name'"

            try ( 
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
                //int columCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

                int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                System.out.println("Column number is: "+columnsNumber );


            }
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
```

Comment: Still same output...It shows 1. But when I am testing only the sql on MySql terminal it gives right ans.

Answer (score -2):

Try `SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name=\"my_b\"`

Just omit the `count(*)` since this returns a single result, while you are looking for all columns.

Comment: Then it shows 19 but the actual column number is 3.

Comment: `information_schema.columns` has a fixed schema.  It's not one column per column in `my_b`, but one *row* per column in `my_b`.